# disable replace mode when i launch vim

Tags: vim

When I run vim it puts me in --REPLACE-- mode, how I put it in command mode or insertion mode.

( And how to activate these commands by default when I run vim?
 - :set nu
 - :set cc=80 
)

**vimrc**

```
if v:lang =~ "utf8$" || v:lang =~ "UTF-8$"
   set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,latin1
endif

set nocompatible    " Use Vim defaults (much better!)
set bs=indent,eol,start     " allow backspacing over everything in insert mode
"set ai         " always set autoindenting on
"set backup     " keep a backup file
set viminfo='20,\"50    " read/write a .viminfo file, don't store more
            " than 50 lines of registers
set history=50      " keep 50 lines of command line history
set ruler       " show the cursor position all the time

" Only do this part when compiled with support for autocommands
if has("autocmd")
  augroup redhat
  autocmd!
  " In text files, always limit the width of text to 78 characters
  " autocmd BufRead *.txt set tw=78
  " When editing a file, always jump to the last cursor position
  autocmd BufReadPost *
  \ if line("'\"") > 0 && line ("'\"") <= line("$") |
  \   exe "normal! g'\"" |
  \ endif
  " don't write swapfile on most commonly used directories for NFS mounts or USB sticks
  autocmd BufNewFile,BufReadPre /media/*,/run/media/*,/mnt/* set directory=~/tmp,/var/tmp,/tmp
  " start with spec file template
  autocmd BufNewFile *.spec 0r /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/template.spec
  augroup END
endif

if has("cscope") && filereadable("/usr/bin/cscope")
   set csprg=/usr/bin/cscope
   set csto=0
   set cst
   set nocsverb
   " add any database in current directory
   if filereadable("cscope.out")
      cs add $PWD/cscope.out
   " else add database pointed to by environment
   elseif $CSCOPE_DB != ""
      cs add $CSCOPE_DB
   endif
   set csverb
endif

" Switch syntax highlighting on, when the terminal has colors
" Also switch on highlighting the last used search pattern.
if &t_Co > 2 || has("gui_running")
  syntax on
  set hlsearch
endif

filetype plugin on

if &term=="xterm"
     set t_Co=8
     set t_Sb=[4%dm
     set t_Sf=[3%dm
endif

" Don't wake up system with blinking cursor:
" http://www.linuxpowertop.org/known.php
let &guicursor = &guicursor . ",a:blinkon0"
```

VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Dec 21 2016 17:00:20)
Included patches: 1-160

Comment: The `nu` and `cc=80` part is easy: add `set nu` and `set cc=80` in your `.vimrc`. The replace mode part is strange. How do you call vim exactly?

Comment: i do this `$ vim file.txt`

Comment: I copied your vimrc file to my machine and didn't observe the replace mode problem. What's your OS and vim package? Are you using any plugins? Someone else had this problem before: https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen/issues/102 the answer there might help?

Comment: PS: I noticed that some of the `vim` authors and gurus watch questions on https://vi.stackexchange.com/, so that might be a better forum for your question if no one finds your answer here.

Comment: Most likely, your $TERM variable is wrong and it makes vim query some xterm specific extensions, that your terminal not understands, so Vim takes the response and interprets it as input :( This has been fixed in later Vim versions, try a vim 8.1 and it should work, but if you cannot update, at least configure your $TERM variable correctly.

Comment: Hello, i update my vim with this command `sudo yum update vim`. I got this version  _VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Oct 30 2018 19:56:57)_. How i configure the $TERM variable correctly ? (i ll try on vi.stackexchange.com forum as advised).

Comment: Well, what terminal are you actually using and what does `echo $TERM` say?

Comment: Hello, `echo $TERM` return  **cygwin**